# What does "break it down" mean (slang) in Meghan Trainor's "I'm a Lady"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, lyrics

I heard a song that said something about "breaking it down". I looked it up, and it was Meghan Trainor's "I'm A Lady". The lyric goes

> When I **break it down**, it's a work of art.

What does it mean in that context?

Comment: You may get differing interprtations because when it comes to poetry/lyrics and art, the meaning is often left up to the listener, reader or viewer to interpret it. I think it means,: When I really look at it, it (I am) is art. If you get passed all the crap that people say, I am really great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose two possible interpretations.

Here's a larger portion of the lyrics.

> And I'm pretty, pretty cute and I'm pretty smart
>   And when I break it down, it's a work of art
>   And if you feel the same, can you participate?
>   I wanna see you shake, I wanna hear you say
>   And I'm pretty, pretty cute and I'm pretty smart
>   And when I break it down, it's a work of art
>   And if you feel the same, can you participate?
>   I wanna see you shake, I wanna hear you say
>   ([Direct Lyrics](https://www.directlyrics.com/meghan-trainor-im-a-lady-lyrics.html))

One basic interpretation is as follows.

> [break something down](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/break+down)
>   to discuss the details of something by examining its subparts.
>   *Let's break this problem down into its parts and deal with each one separately.*
>   *Breaking down complex problems into their components is almost fun.*
>   *Let's break this issue down and discuss it.*
>   (The Free Dictionary)

Notice that she's analyzing herself in the lyrics and she concludes that her traits are a work of art.

Another meaning of *break it down* is *to dance*, especially, energetic, loose, freestyle dancing. Here is an example: [Ellen and Michelle Obama Break It Down](https://youtu.be/UZO5q0B5wfw?t=3m53s).

So, another interpretation is when she breaks it down (= dances), it's a work of art.